# Any tutorials for Jython on Play Framework

Tags: playframework, jython

I like jython and I don't like Django. So I was thinking if its possible to run jython based apps using play framework. It does support groovy and scala, so theoritically it seems plausible. 
Is there any documentation that I can follow. Coz I didn't find one when I googled it. 
Another reason whY i'm looking at play framework is because I don't like servlet containers too!

Comment: Might have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388406/jython-using-spring-programming-in-python